# Azure web app random restart - Can anyone expand on this recommendation?

Tags: azure

Following a recent investigation into an Azure web api going down (it does not like cold restarts as the queued requests then swamp the server, which 503's),  I received the following:

> Your application was restarted as site binding status changed. This
>   can most likely occur due to recent deployment slot swap operations.
>   In some cases after the swap the web app in the production slot may
>   restart later without any action taken by the app owner. This restart
>   may take place several hours/days after the swap took place. This
>   usually happens when the underlying storage infrastructure of Azure
>   App Service undergoes some changes. When that happens the application
>   will restart on all VMs at the same time which may result in a cold
>   start and a high latency of the HTTP requests. This event occurred
>   multiple times during the day.

The recommendation was

> to minimize the random cold starts, you can set this app setting
>   WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG to 1 in every slot of
>   the app.

Can someone please elaborate on this? 
Am I right in thinking that if we ever do a swap (eg: staging to production) at some random point in the future the app will restart?

What does the app setting actually do and how will it stop Azure restarting the production slot?

**Answer** from the link provided by Patrick Goode, whose google-foo is far better than mine

> "Just to explain the specifics of what
>   WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG app setting does. By
>   default we put the site’s hostnames into the site’s
>   applicationHost.config file “bindings” section. Then when the swap
>   happens the hostnames in the applicationHost.config get out of sync
>   with what the actual site’s hostnames are. That does not affect the
>   app in anyway while it is running, but as soon as some storage event
>   occurs, e.g. storage volume fail over, that discrepancy causes the
>   worker process app domain to recycle. If you use this app setting then
>   instead of the hostnames we will put the sitename into the “bindings”
>   section of the appHost.config file. The sitename does not change
>   during the swap so there will be no such discrepancy after the swap
>   and hence there should not be a restart."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this setting is supposed to prevent 'random cold restarts'

[https://ruslany.net/2019/06/azure-app-service-deployment-slots-tips-and-tricks](https://ruslany.net/2019/06/azure-app-service-deployment-slots-tips-and-tricks/)